# for loop adding the variable name to a formula

Tags: r, for-loop, random-forest

I am trying to perform Random Forest regression in R and have come across several problems and have fixed most of them myself however I just cannot get around this last issue.
I have a list of files I wish to read in and that is no problem (I use a for loop).

```
library(randomForest)
set.seed(51)

file<- c("file1","file2","file3")
targets<- c("X1.ts","ts2","ts3")

for (i in 1:length(file)){
d_names<-paste("C:\\location\folder\",drugs[i],".txt",sep="")
dataset<- read.table(d_names, header=TRUE, row.names=1)
ind<-sample(2,nrow(dataset), replace=TRUE)

#TRAINING DATASET1 PREDICTING DATASET2
train_one.rf<- randomForest(dataset[ind==1,][[1]] ~ .-targets[i], data=dataset[ind==1,], prob=c(0.7,0.3))
dset2.pred<- predict(train_one.rf, newdata=dataset[ind==2,])

#TRAINING DATASET2 PREDICTING DATASET1
train_two.rf<- randomForest(dataset[ind==2,][[1]] ~ .-targets[i], data=dataset[ind==2,], prob=c(0.7,0.3))
dset1.pred<- predict(train_two.rf, newdata=dataset[ind==1,])

}
```

The nature of Random Forest is that I have to model the data excluding the column I wish to predict. to do so I have to use the:

```
dataset[ind==1,][[1]] ~ .-target[i]
```

It is the *target[i]* i wish to add the name of the column (from targets) for each run of Random Forest. I have tried assigning it to a variable and also subbing the loop variable in also but to no avail. I guess the formula part in R requires something a bit more elegant knowledge than I have.

Thnaks in advance,

Jcrow

Comment: what is targets? Are these the same columns in all data?

Comment: targets are a column defines in each file that is read in. It seems to read the column name but if I want to automate the process for the i need to read in each file and have the column name associated with that file

Comment: As far as I understand, you are reading each file and in each file you are using first element of targets, and then second element of targets, and then third element of targets, right? My code below is for each file and for first element of targets. If you want for each elements of each file, you can easily modify the following code. But, before I do that please let me know if this is what you are looking after?

Comment: You are correct in so far as I need the first file and the first element of targets, then i need the second file and the second element of targets etc, The for loop can do so but my issue is with the formula part (y ~.) this calls the data from dataset column 1 marked as ind==1 (in the above example), I then need to call it against the rest of the data excluding the column 1 as this will be modelling against itself. I know I can use y ~ .-V1 however if the V1 name changes with every file I need to also have the V1 element also changing. Sorry for my confusing postulation of the question

Comment: Not a problem. I am trying to do `as.formula` but I didn't have the sample data to test. Can you post sample data?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution using the mtcars data broken into two datasets as data1 and data2. (There is no R `for loop` here )

```
data1<-mtcars[1:15,]
data2<-mtcars[16:nrow(mtcars),]
mydata<-list(data1,data2)

targets<-list("mpg~.","cyl~.")

Map(function(x) Map(function(y) randomForest(as.formula(y),data=x,importance=TRUE,proximity=TRUE), targets),mydata)

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]

Call:
 randomForest(formula = as.formula(y), data = x, importance = TRUE,      proximity = TRUE) 
               Type of random forest: regression
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 3

          Mean of squared residuals: 4.637522
                    % Var explained: 63.98

[[1]][[2]]

Call:
 randomForest(formula = as.formula(y), data = x, importance = TRUE,      proximity = TRUE) 
               Type of random forest: regression
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 3

          Mean of squared residuals: 0.2455641
                    % Var explained: 89.04


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]

Call:
 randomForest(formula = as.formula(y), data = x, importance = TRUE,      proximity = TRUE) 
               Type of random forest: regression
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 3

          Mean of squared residuals: 10.90303
                    % Var explained: 78.93

[[2]][[2]]

Call:
 randomForest(formula = as.formula(y), data = x, importance = TRUE,      proximity = TRUE) 
               Type of random forest: regression
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 3

          Mean of squared residuals: 0.1623937
                    % Var explained: 95.69


Warning messages:
1: In randomForest.default(m, y, ...) :
  The response has five or fewer unique values.  Are you sure you want to do regression?
2: In randomForest.default(m, y, ...) :
  The response has five or fewer unique values.  Are you sure you want to do regression?
```

**Note**: The inner `Map` function repeats the regression for different elements of targets whereas the outer `Map` function repeats the regression for different elements of mydata.